# Tesseract Linking Issue

Tags: c++, linker, tesseract, codelite

I have an issue trying to run the very basic code example from the Tesseract GitHub. I don't know if it's my inability to express myself in searches queries or if I'm in too deep.

I have the following code, copied and pasted from the API Example section on their page:

```
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

int main()
{
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete [] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);

    return 0;
}
```

Running this produces the following error messages:

```
/home/xweque/Documents/home/docThor/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()'
/home/xweque/Documents/home/docThor/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `pixRead'
/home/xweque/Documents/home/docThor/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetImage(Pix*)'
/home/xweque/Documents/home/docThor/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetUTF8Text()'
/home/xweque/Documents/home/docThor/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::End()'
/home/xweque/Documents/home/docThor/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `pixDestroy'
./Debug/main.cpp.o: In function `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*)':
/usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:240: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*, tesseract::OcrEngineMode, char**, int, GenericVector<STRING> const*, GenericVector<STRING> const*, bool)'
```

I'm using CodeLite 10 and `g++` as the compiler, officially supported. I'm using the following as my sole include path `/usr/include/`. Both .h are in there. I'm fairly certain it is a linking error since I've tried other code snippets, nothing official and nothing I've saved so not referenced but gives an indication.

**EDIT**

`g++` output:

```
/tmp/ccgCPJv6.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `Magick::InitializeMagick(char const*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::Image()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::read(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::Geometry(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, bool)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::crop(Magick::Geometry const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::~Geometry()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x12f): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::write(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1bb): undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::~Geometry()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'
/tmp/ccgCPJv6.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x54): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Magick::Exception'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**EDIT 2**

```
xweque@LM-viktor /usr/lib $ ls -la /usr/lib | grep "tesseract"
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root    6741822 Apr  8  2016 libtesseract.a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root         21 Apr  8  2016 libtesseract.so -> libtesseract.so.3.0.4
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root         21 Apr  8  2016 libtesseract.so.3 -> libtesseract.so.3.0.4
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root    3074104 Apr  8  2016 libtesseract.so.3.0.4
xweque@LM-viktor /usr/lib $ ls -la /usr/lib | grep "lept"
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root    4592626 Feb  4  2016 liblept.a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root         16 Feb  4  2016 liblept.so -> liblept.so.5.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root         16 Feb  4  2016 liblept.so.5 -> liblept.so.5.0.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root    2370000 Feb  4  2016 liblept.so.5.0.0
```

Full g++ command:

```
g++ -o main /home/xweque/Documents/home/docThor/main.cpp -I/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib/ -llept -ltesseract
```

Comment: When you said "both libs are there" did you mean that the .lib files are in /usr/include? That might explain your problem, since presumably /usr/lib is the intended home.

Comment: @user888379 Oh, no. Meant .h

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin Edited post

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin they're all in /usr/lib/

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin Made edits answering your comment

Comment: There are no references to `Magick::*` functions in your example code. Please post an accurate [mcve]